# What is the trick behind "launch application holding [modifier key]"?

Tags: macos, cocoa

iTunes and Reeder (and I'm sure lots of other) applications has an ability to modify startup behavior whenever they are launched while holding ⌥ (option) key. I tried looking at `NSApplicationDelegate` methods, but none seem to add any sort of hint to what I'm looking for. How is this functionality achieved?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your application delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching: method

```
NSUInteger flags = ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask);

BOOL isOptionPressed = (flags == NSAlternateKeyMask);
```

(Edited to match awesome answer [Declaring and checking/comparing (bitmask-)enums in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166895/declaring-and-checking-comparing-bitmask-enums-in-objective-c) 
Previously this was
`BOOL isOptionPressed = (0 != (flags & NSAlternateKeyMask));`
But the zero checking is not necessary to check if a bit mask for equality, unless the bit mask itself represents all zeros in binary.
The provided link gives greater detail.
)

Comment: Please refer to the amazing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166895/declaring-and-checking-comparing-bitmask-enums-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Francis McGrew's answer needs improvement before it can work, but I still see no solution via that route.  The answer as stated does not compile.  An actual NSEvent pointer is needed for modifierFlags, which is not a class method as the answer would suggest.

One would hope that the needed event might be obtained by the following.

```
NSEvent *event = [NSApp currentEvent];
```

However when called from applicationDidFinishLaunching the resulting event is nil.  At least this is true in my testing on Snow Leopard.

applicationDidFinishLaunching has an NSNotification argument but I don't know how to make any use of it.

I found a similar question on cocobuilder.com from 2007 and the answer there is basically to call the carbon function GetCurrentKeyModifiers and convert the carbon flags to cocoa form.

See http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/176882-detecting-modifier-keys-at-launch.html

Comment: You have said alot but without any actual or even potential solutions, try and directly answer the question in future

Comment: + (NSEventModifierFlags)modifierFlags NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6); is a class method no need for an instance