# Declaring and checking/comparing (bitmask-)enums in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, enums, bitmask

You know in Cocoa there is this thing, for example you can create a `UIView` and do:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I have a custom `UIView` with multiple states, which I have defined in an `enum` like this:

```
enum DownloadViewStatus {
  FileNotDownloaded,
  FileDownloading,
  FileDownloaded
};
```

For each created subview, I set its `tag`: `subview1.tag = FileNotDownloaded;`

Then, I have a custom setter for the view state which does the following:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
  if (subview.tag == viewStatus)
    subview.hidden = NO;
  else
    subview.hidden = YES;
}
```

But **what I am trying to do**, is to allow this:

```
subview1.tag = FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded;
```

So my `subview1` shows up in two states of my view. Currently, it doesn't show up in any of those two states since the `|` operator seems to add the two enum values.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your `(subview.tag == viewStatus)` looks wrong to me. Should be `((subview.tag & viewStatus) != 0x0)`, unless you want to just check for exact matching. In which case you wouldn't need a bitmask in the first place, but just a plain old enum. See second half of my answer.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

### Declaring Bitmasks:

Alternatively to assigning absolute values (`1`, `2`, `4`, …) you can declare **[bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask)** (how these are called) like this:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
  FileNotDownloaded = (1 << 0), // => 00000001
  FileDownloading   = (1 << 1), // => 00000010
  FileDownloaded     = (1 << 2)  // => 00000100
} DownloadViewStatus;
```

or using modern ObjC's `NS_OPTIONS`/`NS_ENUM` macros:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, DownloadViewStatus) {
  FileNotDownloaded = (1 << 0), // => 00000001
  FileDownloading   = (1 << 1), // => 00000010
  FileDownloaded    = (1 << 2)  // => 00000100
};
```

(see [Abizern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168299/227536) for more info on the latter)

The concept of bitmasks is to (usually) define each enum value with a single bit set.

Hence `OR`ing two values does the following:

```
DownloadViewStatus status = FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded; // => 00000101
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  00000001 // FileNotDownloaded
| 00000100 // FileDownloaded
----------
= 00000101 // (FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded)
```

### Comparing Bitmasks:

One thing to keep in mind when checking against bitmasks:

#### Checking for exact equality:

Let's assume that status is initialized like this:

```
DownloadViewStatus status = FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded; // => 00000101
```

If you want to check if `status` **equals** `FileNotDownloaded`, you can use:

```
BOOL equals = (status == FileNotDownloaded); // => false
```

which is equivalent to:

```
   00000101 // (FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded)
== 00000100 // FileDownloaded
-----------
=  00000000 // false
```

#### Checking for "membership":

If you want to check if `status` merely **contains** `FileNotDownloaded`, you need to use:

```
BOOL contains = (status & FileNotDownloaded) != 0; // => true

   00000101 // (FileNotDownloaded | FileDownloaded)
&  00000100 // FileDownloaded
-----------
=  00000100 // FileDownloaded
!= 00000000 // 0
-----------
=  00000001 // 1 => true
```

See the subtle difference (and why your current "if"-expression is probably wrong)?

Comment: @Abizern: Thanks! Thought this question deserved a bit more explanation than had previously been provided.

Comment: Yeah but you're formatting the binary values as hexadecimal values (preceded by 0x). Bitmasks work on the bit level. Simple mistake, I'm sure you didn't even notice it. But someone might look at that and incorrectly assume that you can have a max of 8 options per enum, when you can actually have a maximum of 32 distinct options. Correction:  

`FileNotDownloaded = (0x1 << 0), // => %...00000001` etc.

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman: You are absolutely right. Strange you're the first to notice. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Apple provides a wonderful pair of macros NS_ENUM and NS_OPTION for enum and bit mask declarations. Use them. See NSHipster site for some good descriptions.

Comment: Fully aware of them. ;) (See Abizern's answer) Anyway, added a variation with `NS_OPTIONS` for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on why the need for the `!= 0` ? I cannot seem to get it to give a false positive without the not zero condition. Am I missing something obvious/obtuse about bit masks?

Comment: @uchuugaka: `BOOL` is usually defined as `typedef signed char BOOL;` (most recent runtime, typedefs onto C99's `bool`, IIRC). As such any value larger than `CHAR_MAX` with its lower eight bits being all zeros, while in nature being a positive value, will turn into `NO` upon casting to `BOOL` (be it ex- or implicitly). Which while technically correct, is most likely unexpected and unwanted by the developer.

Comment: Right. I see what you mean about overflows. Perhaps it should simply be ((status & FileNotDownloaded) == FileNotDownloaded) so tag there are only two results possible.

Comment: @uchuugaka: One way to do it, sure. Readability/clarity/correctness very much depends on the context, of course. ;)

Answer (score 20):

While @Regexident has provided an excellent answer - I must mention the modern Objective-C way of declaring Enumerated options with `NS_OPTIONS`:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, DownloadViewStatus) {
  FileNotDownloaded = 0,
  FileDownloading   = 1 << 0,
  FileDownloaded    = 1 << 1
};
```

Further Reference:

- [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/)
- [I Am The Walrus](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2012/11/ns_enum-and-ns_options/)

Comment: Yes the NS_ENUM and NS_OPTION macros are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum DownloadViewStatus {
  FileNotDownloaded = 1,
  FileDownloading = 2,
  FileDowloaded = 4
};
```

This will let you perform bitwise OR's and AND's effectively.

Comment: The standard way to define the values is `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, `1 << 2` etc. This makes it clear you are working with bits and masks.

Comment: @AhmedAlHafoudh: The article doesn't however address OP's second problem: working with bitmasks (vs. simply declaring them). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Useful function you can use for bitmask checking to improve readability.

```
BOOL bitmaskContains(NSUInteger bitmask, NSUInteger contains) {
    return (bitmask & contains) != 0;
}
```

Comment: More strict `(bitmask & contains) == contains` - it will work even with zero `contains`