# Multiple UISwitches to target NSArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

can anyone help me here?

I'm trying to create a fairly simple flashcards app, but I'd like to have the flashcards' images divided up into categories, such as "beginner", "easy", "medium" and "difficult", and I'd like to use `UISwitches` to permit the user to turn on these flashcards in any combination. So for example he could have "beginner" and "medium" but not the other two... or any other on/off combination he wants.

I was intending to use `arc4random` on each screen touch to select a random flashcard image from the categories the user has switched on, so I'm presuming the best way to store the image resources is in `NSArrays` - one `NSArray` for each category.

All the sample code or tutorials I can find deal only with one switch at a time.

Any help here please?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Carl. Where I'm stuck is in using arc4random and trying to turn on/off sections of the parameters for the random number I'd generate. Say there were forty slides in total (10 x beginner, 10 x easy, 10 x medium and 10 x hard), and the user had the UISwitches for all except "medium" turned on, I'd have to disregard the random numbers generated between 20 and 30, until he changed his mind and switched some others off and on. Then the corresponding random number generation would have to change according to which switches were on.

Answer (score 0):

This is where knowing binary logic would help.  Let's say you assign a bitmask field to every question that says whether it's easy, medium, hard, etc.  (Using a bitmask you could also make one problem appear in multiple categories, maybe some questions are easy and medium?)

Each time a switch is flipped, adjust your comparison bitmask appropriately.  When it's time to pick the questions you can just run through each one and use a binary AND operation against your bitmask to see if it is appropriate to be included in the question list.

See this answer for how to declare and compare a bitmask enum:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16167768/96683

Comment: Hi jsd. Thank you for that. I hadn't heard of bitmask fields before - it doesn't appear in my copy of "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" but your idea and your link seem to make sense.

Comment: Your book may assume you knew about them from plain C, since that's where they originated. They are handy for packing a bunch of information into a small amount of storage.