# Core Data Model design - 8 bools or 1 NSString? Core Data iOS swift

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I hope this is the right forum to ask this sort of question. I'm trying to minimize the amount of data performing a sync with iCloud, while ensuring ideal app speed as well... I am trying to use an efficient model... My application (which is a basic checklist application) will have around 8 variables that can be marked as "owned" for each item.

Would it be better to create 8 attributes as Boolean attributes or a single String attribute? With the string attribute, I would simply include 8 numbers like "00000000" or "10000000" or "10001000" with each character of the string linked to a particular item and retrieved by looking for a particular index of the string.

My initial thought is that the 8 booleans would allow for faster reading and writing, and would have a minimal footprint, but I would appreciate some more intelligent feedback from the experts.

Comment: What about NS_OPTIONS and just plain NSInteger ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend nothing of this to minimize memory usage. Reason is that bool costs 1 byte - 8 bit (but wee need only one and other 7 wont be used), string same but with characters. If you want to minimize memory usage - than use 1 byte. Because 1 byte - 8 bit you can set each bit with 1 or 0 using memory mask(bit mask). And than all your values will be allocated in 1 byte what will use eight time less memory than bool. How to use memory mask(bit mask) you can read this topic

[Declaring and checking/comparing (bitmask-)enums in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166895/declaring-and-checking-comparing-bitmask-enums-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

I would think any difference in speed or memory is likely to be marginal.  Design and code it in the most logical way, which at first sight seems to be using 8 booleans.  For example, if you need to fetch a subset of the data based on the boolean values, it will be far easier to construct the required predicate.